# How to read parameter values from a TestCase in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: c#-4.0, testcase, microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to execute the testcases programatically using the microsoft test manager using c#. 
For that I want to read the parameter values stored in Microsoft Test Manager.
Please suggest me how to do that
Eg:- Read the value of internal paramter "MY Value"
I tried to enter the image but its not working ...

Regards 
Harsh

Answer (score 8):

I suppose you want to read the parameters from the datasource of the Test Case that your automated test implements.

You have to associate your test with the Test Case's Id on TFS.

Try the following code.

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
    public DataRow DataRow { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", 
        "http://localhost:8080/tfs/[CollectionName];[ProjectName]", "[TestCaseId]", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        string column1 = TestContext.DataRow[0].ToString(); // read parameter by column index
        string column2 = TestContext.DataRow["Column2"].ToString(); //read parameter by column name
    }
}
```

Have in mind that your TestMethod will run one time for each row (iteration) of the Test Case's datasource.

Comment: Is the DataSource defined with the brackets around those Field names? Or are we meant to substitute with the values in the attribute? Thanks.

Comment: No, you don't need the brackets. Replace them with the actual values (e.g. "[TestCaseId]"--> "100").

Answer (score 0):

I think what you describe is Data-Driven Coded UI tests.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx